# Good grades vs published research

Tags: research-undergraduate

I'm in the penultimate year of my undergraduate education and about 20% of the year's grade is a research project. It is essentially an exercise since not everybody is expected to produce much in a way of scientific contribution at this stage. It is however possible to do insightful, publishable research, which would be my first time.

Doing publishable research would take a lot of time. Because there is a finite amount of hours in a day and week etc., I see three options:

- Distribute my time evenly, and get good exam and project grades.
- Prioritize exams (I expect my score to be about 80-90%) over the project.
- Try and do reasonably well on exams (score about 70%), but put everything I've got into the project.

I think I am knowledgeable in the area and I'll  be able to contribute and create publishable research and write a paper if I prioritise it.

If I would like to go and do a PhD and then become a professor, I think a publication is worth more than ridiculously high grades. Assuming I won't drop below 70%average upon graduation; should I marginalise the exams?

Comment: Where do you intend to study? Country? But strategizing in this way feels like a fool's game to me.

Comment: It's not necessary to ask questions wrapped in hypotheticals - edited for readability

Comment: I don't mean to be rude - but how do you *know* you can do publishable research? Did a professor tell you? I ask because if it's your first time, you may be wrong about the amount of work and resources needed (I certainly was). Class projects aren't usually do 50% more and publish it.

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't marginalize anything, and I don't think strategizing about this sort of thing is likely to be beneficial.

When you apply to graduate school, your application will be judged against other students who have both excellent grades and excellent research projects.

Once you've done the best you can, yes, it's possible you'll have imperfect grades and you can hope other parts of your application make up for that. You could also find that the time you've poured into a research project results in just a mediocre paper with no triumphant result at all - such is the nature of research.

Try to build the best all-around application you can, and don't put too much stress on how exactly you can game the system.

Comment: Pouring everything you've got; days and nights, hundreds, maybe a thousand+ hours in a single one year is hardly what I would call "gaming the system".

Comment: @Peter Agreed, I wouldn't call that gaming the system either, nor do I. If you're not excited to work on a research project, why go to grad school where that's the primary thing you'll be doing? A PhD takes far more than a thousand hours in a year.

Comment: @BryanKrause a PhD should take ~2 thousands hours in a year. Good to see the transparent declaration it is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

At least some graduate programs require a certain undergraduate GPA as a requirement for admission, and it's likely to be above 70% (although there might be exceptions made in special cases). Regardless of whether a high GPA is more or less impressive than published work, it'd be good to identify those requirements and stay above them.

Also, don't assume that the two sides are fully independent. A reasonably broad background education can be useful when doing research. It provides you with a better set of tools with which to approach your problem (or at least lets you know that such tools are likely to exist). (As an extreme example of someone reinventing the wheel due to an insufficiently broad background education, consider [this paper](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eehallman/math1B/TaisMethod.pdf) from 1994, that reinvents the trapezoid rule from basic calculus (popularized by Newton in the 17th century, but possibly also in use in [Babylon circa 50 BC](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.aad8085)).

Comment: I agree, but the exams are designed so that you could train a monkey to take them. Good exam grades have nothing to do with knowledge, you're meant not to fail by making them absurdly easy and irrelevant.

Comment: @Peter A lot depends on the specific exam, but it's been my experience that while passing such exams isn't especially strong evidence that you have a good background education, if you *do* have that background, you can ace exams like that without putting in any additional effort. (Assuming the content of the exam isn't *completely* irrelevant trivia. You know better than I do whether that's the case here.)

Comment: Not true. being even very knowledgeable maybe be a hindrance. Supose an exam question is ambiguous and open to interpretation. You know it because you have some understanding of the theory. The professor who wrote the question doesn't seem to have the same insight and doesn't know that the question is vague. You therefore spent 30 min to provide the answer to the question asked rather than spending 5 min to do what is expected of you. And you'll know what is expected by watching and rewarching recorded lectures, rereading lecture notes. A COMPLETE waste of time that doesn't develop you.

Comment: A specific example: an exam question asked something about radioactivity of Uranium-238. It has a half life of some 4.5 billion years. I've always known that. It's about the same age as the age of the Earth. Common knowledge. However, the professor didn't know that and made a mistake by using this number but calling it mean lifetime. If confused me because I interpreted it as half-life. My mistake, but the lack of ignorance in this case led me astray. Exam-studying can make you ignorant!

Answer (score 2):

Having been in this exact situation myself, I will argue that the long-term positive effects of publications are worth significantly more than grades. When writing my masters thesis, I choose a controversial subject which resulted in a poor grade, however, the thesis turned into a paper which has helped me land interviews for both PhD and industrial positions.
It should be noted that this is from a  Northeren European context. Many people here are quite sceptical as to the value of grades.

Next to this, I invite you to consider what you enjoy the most - conducting reserach or acing exams. It is virtually impossible to plan anything in detail when it comes to career or professional achievements. One rarely regrets having done something out of passion.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a reasonable question to ask about how to prioritize your time and I don't think it's "gaming the system" to think about this carefully.

At your level, I would not sacrifice good grades, because grades are an important metric that grad schools use, because you actually need to learn the material in undergrad well to do good research later, and because your plan to compensate for mediocre grades by having solid research is very risky since it depends on your research succeeding in a fixed timeframe, which no one can guarantee. Even more than succeeding, you are banking on this research being sufficiently interesting and impactful, that grad school committees are so impressed that they overlook your senior grades. Maybe you could justify lower grades if you were **sure** you could get a high impact publication out of your research, but I doubt you can be sure of this. I would set the minimum bar for yourself at getting good grades, and completing the senior project at the level that is done by most students. If you can make the senior project *even better* without sacrificing your grades, then by all means, do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely negligent to listen to advice telling you to focus on a research project to the detriment of your other studies.

The project is just one small part of your overall grades, intended as an *introduction* to research through a self-study project (likely the first and only non-structured aspect in one's entire degree) led by a supervisor.

It is likely the *one and only* aspect of your entire degree where the end result is uncertain and potentially completely open-ended.

If it was intended as an avenue for students to spend all their time on to the detriment of their other studies it would obviously be completely inappropriate - of course it's not intended to be that way.

If at the *first* opportunity for some flexibility one then decides to dedicate all their energy to X to the exclusion of all their other responsibilities, *especially* when the outcome is likely the most unpredictable it would ever be for someone attempting to do research (at the very beginning of their first opportunity to do X), it simply sets a bad precedent for the future and indicates an inability to manage basic responsibilities.